# kotlin object class not found when proguard is enabled

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

My application works well when proguard is disabled, but once enable it breaks the functionality.
I have a class called CachecManager which is not accessible once proguard is enabled.
Here is my class

```
object CacheManger {
    fun setData(data: String) {
        val yourFilePath: String = BaseClass.appContext.filesDir.toString() + "/" + USER_DATA
        val yourFile = File(yourFilePath)
        val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(yourFile)
        fileOutputStream.write(data.toByteArray())
        fileOutputStream.flush()
        fileOutputStream.close()
    }
}
```

This is my proguard file

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

#project related
-keep class com.appname.constants
-keep class com.appname.models.** { *; }
-keepnames class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
#-keep class <class>$Companion { *; }



-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-dontwarn kotlin.**
-keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {
    <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}
-assumenosideeffects class kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics {
    static void checkParameterIsNotNull(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String);
}
```

This is error which i am getting

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.appname.cachemanager.CacheManger" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.appname-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.appname-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.appname-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: i can`t remember what was solution in my case. But you can add @Keep annotation as well.

Comment: also check after uninstalling the app and then installing it again.